# Getting exception while using mockito to get req.getRequestURI()

Tags: java, node.js, mocking, mockito, request-uri

I am facing issue while mocking a requestURI().any help in this issue will be benifical
i am trying to mock using mockito below  line

```
String reqURI25 = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length());
```

**I tried with**

```
Mockito.when(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().substring(httpServletRequest.getContextPath().length())).thenReturn("/test/test"); 
Mockito.when(httpServletRequest.getParameter("name")).thenReturn(name);
Mockito.when(httpServletRequest.getParameter("category")).thenReturn(category);
```

**exception - i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException for**

```
    String reqURI25 = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length()); 

    private String category="test";                                        
    private String name="test";     
    private String isoLanguage="en";  
    private String isoCountry="US";                   
    private String countryName="United States of America";                                   
    private String isoLCCountry="us";             
    private String charsetEncoding="iso-8859-1";                                                                                                                  
    String reqURI25 = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length());  

         //determine the last forward slash
            //to the right is the form name
            //to the left is the category
            int lastSlash = reqURI25.lastIndexOf("/");
            int uriLen = reqURI25.length();
            String form_name="";
            String init_form_name = reqURI25.substring(lastSlash + 1);

            boolean skipLastChar = false;

            if (((lastSlash + 9) == uriLen) && (init_form_name.equals("director")))
            {
                Enumeration parameters = req.getParameterNames();

                while (parameters.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String parameterName = (String)parameters.nextElement();

                    if (parameterName.equals("form_name")) {
                        form_name = req.getParameter(parameterName);
                    }
                }
                    if (!form_name.equals("")) {
                        reqURI25 = reqURI25.substring(0, lastSlash) + "/" + form_name;
                        lastSlash = reqURI25.lastIndexOf("/");
                        uriLen = reqURI25.length();

                        logger.debug(method,"reconfigured formname in querystring reqURI25 = "+reqURI25);
                    }
            }



            if ((lastSlash + 1) == uriLen)
            {
                lastSlash = reqURI25.substring(0, uriLen-1).lastIndexOf("/");
                skipLastChar = true;
            }

            logger.debug(method,"lastSlash = "+lastSlash);

            //category=req.getParameter("category"); // old 2.0 engine
            // handle for if lastSlash = 0, there is no category

            if (lastSlash == 0)
            {
                category="";
            }
            else
            {
                category=reqURI25.substring(1, lastSlash);
            }

            logger.debug(method,"category = "+category);
            if (skipLastChar)
            {
                name=reqURI25.substring(lastSlash + 1, uriLen - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                name=reqURI25.substring(lastSlash + 1);
            }

            logger.debug(method,"name = "+name);

            if (name.equals("form.do"))
            {
                name=req.getParameter("name");
                category=req.getParameter("category");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.log("Invalid form category or name, EXCEPTION: "+e);
            throw new FileNotFoundException("FILE_NOT_FOUND");
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the Error Stack as well?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
IdTest.test(IdTest.java:64)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:4:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to mock too much in one go, you need to do each method call individually, like (might need to tweak it for off-by-one errors, but you get the idea):

```
Mockito.when(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("https://example.com/test/test");
Mockito.when(httpServletRequest.getContextPath()).thenReturn("https://example.com/");
```

This is actually a good thing in a way, because you're now testing the substring logic in that line as well.